# Adjusting Celery concurrency with Google Kubernetes Engine CPUs

Tags: kubernetes, celery, google-kubernetes-engine

I am writing an application that is running in my Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE) which is running on n2 machines (2 virtual CPU's per node). My cluster contains 3 nodes so 6 virtual CPUs.

I am running celery in my container with the following command:

```
celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker1@%h
```

And I want to know what would be the optimal number of workers and optimal concurrency per worker in order to have the maximum amount of celery tasks running at the same time without affecting the performance or losing the tasks from redis.

Some explanation about the relationship between the two would be splendid.
If I want to increase the number of tasks running, should I increase the number of workers, or concurrency of the same worker, or the GKE cluster size (number of nodes) to assign more CPUs?

Comment: IMO, it depends of how your tasks runs and how is the CPU consume. You need to take in consideration the idle period, so if you have an specific time you know the tasks will run, you can have small vm instances and increase the number of nodes in the cluster, in this way when your tasks ends you can remove the extra nodes and keep your avareage workload running in few small vm instances to save some money.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the autoscaling feature.

Comment: The is missing data: what is your pod's cpu request? limit? memory request? limit? do you know how much memory each task consume? how much cpu?